# How to check whether a radio buttons and checkboxes are selected in form loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am making my first js plugin to validate the html form. I have figure it out for text fields but having some issues in choosing best way to validate radio buttons and checkbox. Since there can be multiple radio groups, each group having many radio buttons. What i am doing is looping around form elements like below.

```
 _self.on("submit", function(event) {
                console.log('form submitted ');
                _self.find('.'+settings.errorClass).each(function(){
                    let type = $(this).attr('type');
                    let val = $(this).val();
                    validate(type, val);
                });
validate = function(type, val) {
            console.log(type);
            switch (type) {
                case 'text':
                    validateText(val);
                    break;
                case 'radio':
                    validaRadio(val);
                    break;
             case 'checkbox':
                validaCheckbox(val);
                break;
                default:

            }
```

Now in above code validaRadio function is called for every radio button in each group which i do not want. I want to validate radio button by group (name). So that if there are two radio groups each having four radio buttons then validateRadio function should be called twice by each radio group not eight times.
Let me know if you guys some better solutions to above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of `checkedRadioNames` for names you've already sent to the verifier. If there's a radio button with a name already verified, skip it.

```
_self.on("submit", function(event) {
  console.log('form submitted ');
  const checkedRadioNames = [];
  _self.find('.'+settings.errorClass).each(function(){
    const type = $(this).attr('type');
    const val = $(this).val();
    if (type === 'radio') {
      const name = $(this).attr('name');
      if (checkedRadioNames.includes(name)) return;
      validaRadio(val, name);
    } else validate(type, val);
  });
```

Comment: i was thinking about same approach that you have suggested. But is that best apporach ?? i mean how other validation plugin handle radio buttons and checkboxes ?

Comment: I was trying to follow your general method as much as possible, but it would be far more elegant to simply iterate over every radio/checkbox name and check that each name has an element with the `:checked` property - if you're indeed looking to make sure every input area has something checked. (I don't know what your `validaRadio` and such methods are actually checking)

Comment: Suppose i have one radio groups to validate in the form having 6 radio buttons in which third one is checked so If  I iterate over each of then even after finding third one checked loop will go to other elements to check but I dont want that. As there can be multiple radio groups in the form. So if I iterate over all radio then how i will break the loop (when checked found) and know which radio groups have checked radio and there is no need to show error message ?

Comment: What's your goal? Are you trying to make sure all radio fields have something checked?

Comment: My goal is to validate form fields that have some class name attach to it and to show error if that field is empty or radio button/checkboxes are not checked.

Comment: Count up the number of required fields with a Set, and then check to see if the number of `[class="required"]:checked` elements (for instance) is equal. https://jsfiddle.net/Lm6f3n0x/

Answer (score 0):

Your approach isn't necessary. All you have to do is get a collection for each set of radio buttons and check the `length` of the checked items and see if that length is 0.

```js
var groups = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("fieldset"));

// Set up an event callback that checks validity
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.clear();
  // Loop over the button groups (each group is in a container element of some kind - a fieldset here)
  groups.forEach(function(g){
    // Look in the container element for the checked buttons in the group
    // and see if the amount of checked buttons is zero
    if(g.querySelectorAll("input[name^='group']:checked").length === 0){
     // If so, none were selected in that group
     console.log("You must select a choice in " + g.dataset.group);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<fieldset data-group="Group One">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="One"> One
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Two"> Two
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Three"> Three
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Four"> Four
</fieldset>
<fieldset data-group="Group Two">
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="One"> One
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Two"> Two
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Three"> Three
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Four"> Four
</fieldset>
<button type="button">Check</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the answering but i do not want my plugin to depend on the form structure as it can be used by anyone irrespective of the forms HTML.